# writing in Logic: the following sentences

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I have to write these 5 sentences in Logic but I'm not sure that I've done well. If someone can help me, I really appreciate that.

Giovanni loves nature:
Loves(giovanni,nature)

Nature lovers preserve the environment:
∀x loves(x,nature) ⇔ preserve(x,environment)

People who preserve the environment do not leave garbage in the woods: 
∀x ¬leave_g(x,woods) ⇒ preserve(x,environment)

People who preserve the environment do not light fires in the woods:
∀x ¬light_f(x,woods) ⇒ preserve(x,environment)

Comment: I would recommend to very carefully check the directions of all the arrows. It might also be helpful to write out your reasons why the expressions should be this way.

Comment: If I say "People who preserve the environment do not leave garbage in the woods" is the same of saying "If you don't leave garbage in the woods then you preserve the environment". Is it wrong?

Comment: What if you don't leave garbage in the woods, but you light fires in the woods? Do you preserve the environment ("If you don't leave garbage in the woods then you preserve the environment") or not ("People who preserve the environment do not light fires in the woods")?

Comment: "People who failed all their exams do not have degrees from Yale." "If you do not have a degree from Yale, you failed all your exams." Are these also the same?

Comment: ok, it is clear now, thanks a lot.